# Why we can not create a posix thread in a singleton class with thread function as member function of a calss in C++

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, posix

I am trying to create a new thread inside the constructor of a singleton class with pthread_create() and thread function as a member function of the class as given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

class singleton
{
        public:
                static singleton& getInstance()
                {
                        static singleton singleton_wrapper;
                        return singleton_wrapper;
                }

                void* check_func(void *arg)
                {
                        cout << "In thread Func" << endl;
                }

        private:
                singleton()
                {
                        pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, check_func, NULL);
                }

                ~singleton()
                {
                }

                singleton& operator=(singleton const&);
                singleton(singleton const&);

                pthread_t th_id;
};

int main()
{
    singleton& p = singleton::getInstance();
}
```

But when I tried to compile with g++, it is giving following error.

```
singletonthread.cpp: In constructor ‘singleton::singleton()’:
singletonthread.cpp:23:49: error: cannot convert ‘singleton::check_func’ from type ‘void* (singleton::)(void*)’ to type ‘void* (*)(void*)’
pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, check_func, NULL);
```

Can anyone please let me know what is the error or why I can't create a thread using member function of a class?

I don't know how it is duplicate of the another question. This question is specifically about a singleton class and creating a thread inside the constructor of a singleton class.

Comment: I don't know how it is duplicate of the another question. This question is specifically about a singleton class and creating a thread inside the constructor of a singleton class.

Comment: Because the error you got has nothing to do with a singleton, and everything to do with the issue in the other question.